# Can't reach some ASPX pages

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I made some changes in JS code inside of `.ASPX` file, everything works fine locally.
Then I deployed changes to dev server (IIS 10) and now when I try to hit this page from the browser it returns `404`. Meanwhile there's no problem to reach other pages from the same folder.

I also connected to server to check if file is there and it is. So why it might happen?

Comment: In addition to ensuring that the URL path is correct and matches the file deployed on the server, check whether there are any URL rewrite rules in IIS that may affect requests for specific ASPX files. Also, please enable detailed errors in IIS error pages and provide us with the relevant information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis#http-errors-in-iis

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 404 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis You can check the log file to see what the substatus code of the 404 error is to determine why the resource returned as "404 Not Found."